# SwiftUI Navigation link deactivated after switching apps

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am building an EV Station app on IOS, which provides users with a map and pins representing EV Charging Stations. I have a `NavigationLink` with `destination:` another view that applies filters to the map results. And `label:`  A custom built button. The problem is that when I switch apps and returns again to my app the `NavigationLink` is not working anymore, not until I switch apps again and return to my app a second time, only then the `NavigationLink` works again.

This behavior is repeated when I repeat the steps described above.

Below you can see my `MainView` which contains the above mentioned `NavigationLink`. you can also find and clone the whole project [on github](https://github.com/Karageorgiou/reCharge-ios).

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocationUI
import Foundation
import AlertToast

struct MainView: View {    
    @StateObject var locationController = LocationController()
    @StateObject var networkController = NetworkController()
    
    @State public var showingSheet = false
    @State public var dismissSheet = false
    
    @State private var showToast = false
    
    @State public var applyFilters = false
    
    @State public var type1 = false
    @State public var type2 = false
    @State public var csstype1 = false
    @State public var csstype2 = false
    @State public var chademo = false
    @State public var schuko = false
    @State public var tesla = false
    
    @State public var dc = false
    @State public var ac1 = false
    @State public var ac2 = false
    @State public var ac2s = false
    @State public var ac3 = false
    
    @State public var format: Int = 3
    @State public var status: Int = 7
    
    var map: MapView {
        MapView(
            locationController: locationController,
            networkController: networkController,
            showingSheet: $showingSheet,
            dismissSheet: $dismissSheet,
            didSelect: {_ in}
        )
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                map.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                
                LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                    print("tapped")
                    locationController.requestAllowOnceLocationPermission()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .tint(Color("LightBlue"))
                .padding(.bottom, 100 )
                .padding(.leading, 330 )
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: FiltersView(
                        applyFilters: $applyFilters,  
                        type1: $type1, 
                        type2: $type2,  
                        csstype1: $csstype1, 
                        csstype2: $csstype2, 
                        chademo: $chademo, 
                        schuko: $schuko, 
                        tesla: $tesla, 
                        dc: $dc, 
                        ac1: $ac1, 
                        ac2: $ac2, 
                        ac2s: $ac2s, 
                        ac3: $ac3, 
                        format: $format, 
                        status: $status),
                    label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .circular)
                                .fill(Color("LightBlue"))
                            HStack {
                                SwiftUI.Image("Filters")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                .padding(10)
                                Text("Φίλτρα")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular))
                                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                            }
                        }.frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 110, minHeight: 40, maxHeight: 40)
                    })
                    .padding(.bottom, 660 )
                    .padding(.leading, 250 )
            }
            //.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            .background(Color("DeepBlue"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    SwiftUI.Image("Logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .sheet(item: $networkController.activeLocation, onDismiss: onSheetDismiss) { item in
                BottomSheetView(data: item)
                    .onDisappear() {
                        print("dissapear")
                    }
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("Active View: Main")
                if applyFilters {
                    networkController.applyFilters = .constant(true)
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.type1 = type1
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.type2 = type2
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.csstype1 = csstype1
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.csstype2 = csstype2
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.chademo = chademo
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.schuko = schuko
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.tesla = tesla
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.dc = dc
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.ac1 = ac1
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.ac2 = ac2
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.ac2s = ac2s
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.ac3 = ac3
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.format = format
                    NetworkVariables.FilterOptions.status = status
                    Task {
                        await networkController.getToken()
                        showToast.toggle()
                    }
                    applyFilters = false
                }
            }
        }
        .toast(isPresenting: $showToast){
            AlertToast(type: .regular, title: "Βρέθηκαν \(networkController.mapLocations.count) σημεία")
        }
        
    }
    
    func onSheetDismiss() {
        print("sheet dismissed")
        map.dismissSheet = true
    }
}
```

Comment: First you should group all those related `@State` into their own struct `FiltersViewConfig`. Also break up the large body into subviews. That will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example? With this code we need to setup all these package for getting more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. As I had read before, this kind of problem usually happens because the app is running on an `emulator`. So while I was having this problem on physical devices, I realised that the physical devices I was testing were running the app on `Testflight` which is kind of a sandbox as far as I've understood it. So, the problem was caused because the app was running on testflight, when I installed the app directly to an iOS device through USB, it worked just fine.

Thanks for your replies.